# Kentico 9 - Display language selector inside transformation

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am trying to display a language selector inside a transformation.

It works if I add the web parts to a page but defining them inside a transformation doesn't work.

This is what I have currently inside my transformation but the repeater just displays "Nothing!".

```
<cms:LanguageDataSource ID="dsLanguages" ExcludeUntranslatedDocuments="false" ExcludeCurrentCulture="false" runat="server" />

<ul class="sub-menu">
  <cms:BasicRepeater ID="rptLanguages" DataSourceName="dsLanguages" ZeroRowsText="Nothing!" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="<%# Eval("URL") %>"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-<%# Eval("CultureCode") %>"></span><%# Eval("CultureName") %></a>
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </cms:BasicRepeater>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really good question and I see that there is generally a lot of confusion about using Web parts inside **Transformations** or **ASPX templates**.

The main point here is that

> Web parts are not *generally* supported in transformations or ASPX templates

Since Web parts are generally user controls you can register them in transformations, but due to their specific life cycle there is no guarantee that they will actually work. More complex web parts will certainly not work and this seems to be the case for the language selector as well.

The official [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Writing+transformations) states that: (SEE UPDATE)

**<s>Using controls in transformations</s>**

> You can register and use user
>   controls and servers controls inside transformations. See that done
>   Transformation examples. However, using web parts in transformations
>   is not recommended for performance reasons.

However, this is not entirely accurate as they are not **supported at all**. I have already submitted a request to technical writes in Kentico to remedy this.

You could eventually try to make a regular **User control** out of the language selector and register that, although I'm not entirely sure whether it would help. I know that some Kentico default transformation are indeed registering User controls so it might help in some cases.

Generally speaking try to avoid using User controls in transformations whenever you can. I would recommend you to just place the language selector web part outside the transformation, it will be the easiest way to get it working properly without any other adjustments.

UPDATE:

After talking to Kentico teams the note [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K10/Writing+transformations) was changed to reflect the current state to:

> We do NOT recommend using web parts within the code of
>   transformations. This could lead to poor performance and certain web
>   parts may not work correctly within transformations due to their life
>   cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed response! I think I will try to go the user control route for now. If that fails then I might need to rework the menu entirely into a custom web part.

Comment: You're welcome! I have been in contact with Technical writers and they have already updated the documentation to reflect the current state. I also updated my answer. Thanks for the question and hope you can get it to work properly:)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your data source is not returning any data.

If you don't need to generate properties of the data source dynamically in the transformation I suggest you put a Language Data Source web part on the page where it works fine and refer to its `Web part control ID` in the transformation.

The language data source web part is probably missing something from the context. Internally, the `Node` property of the DS uses `DocumentContext.CurrentDocument` which may not be available in the transformation. It's either this or what Enn says about controls having different cycle.

Another option would be putting custom C# code inside `<% %>` brackets and retrieving the data you need programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer rocky! I've got a few options now so I'll see how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Enn, there is probably a problem with the repeater control life cycle, because it's dynamically added to the page. 
Have you tried to use the **CMSRepeater** control instead of the **BasicRepater** with the **DelayedLoading** property set to **true**?